# 2nd generation Intel Processor vs newer gen?

Tags: graphics-card, cpu, gaming, sandy-bridge

I'm interested in getting a gaming computer by buying an HP Z210 for $210 which is actually pretty decent with 4 gigs of 1333 ram and a quad core i5 running at 3.2 or something like that and slapping a $200 graphics card in it, but there has to be a place that cut corners.

My question is, since I know that it's using a sandy bridge (2nd generation processor), is there that significant of a difference between the different generations, such as the difference between AMD and Intel (sorta like how 2 ghz on an i3 matches a 3 ghz quad core amd processor? Will it render worse?) (btw I'm not just using it for gaming, but am planning on using photoshop, illustrator, word processing all for school and blender to create modded weapons for CoD WaW Zombie maps, so will it also render that program worse than a newer gen?)

Comment: Why would you purchase a new compute with a 5 generation old CPU in it?

Comment: I imagine he's going for 2nd-hand / refurb mate.  Unless you know somewhere to get new Z210s for 200 bucks??

Comment: @BlueCompute - If the author is purchasing used equipment then this question about performance against 5 generation old CPUs and newer hardware does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using cpubenchmark.net to see the performance difference between two different processors of the same ghz but different generations.  I just google cpubenchmark.net followed by the CPU model number.

I've found that there can be a decent difference, and also it can be worth considering what the "turbo" rating is on each CPU as I don't know how much that factors into the cpubenchmark rating.